# Problem : how can I copy/paste this in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm working with the vim editor and I found `y`,`yw` respectively to copy a line and a word but how can I do the following task in vim?

www.p`ack.goo`gle.com

From this line how can I copy and paste `ack.goo` using vim editor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move cursor under `a`, press <kbd>v</kbd>, use arrow key to select until `o`, press <kbd>y</kbd>. Then move cursor to where you want to paste the text, press <kbd>p</kbd>. Done.

Comment: Try vimtutor as your first step learning vim (:

Comment: ye I'm gonna refer that soon.

Comment: Why not do this?`0fay2fo`.Though visual selection is better if you don't wanna count,but always rely on f<character>

Comment: arrrrows are evil! :)

Answer (score 5):

`y` is followed by a movement, so, like you said, `yw` will copy a word because `w` is the movement that takes you forward one word.

You can also type a number before an action *or* before a movement (or both, I suppose, but that multiplies the numbers and that just seems silly) to repeat the action/movement that many times, so to yank 5 words you can type `5yw` or `y5w`.

In your example, `l` moves the cursor left, so if the cursor is on the "a" you want, you can do `y7l` or `7yl`.

Comment: Us `vi` oldtimers are always counting chars, words or lines because we often use things like y7l, c3w or d5d.